# What to set uwsgi uid and gid to?

Tags: nginx, freebsd, socket, uwsgi

I'm trying to have nginx connect to a uwsgi socket on FreeBSD. I've set the socket to 666 but whenever I issue a request in my browser I can see the following in my nginx logs:

```
2017/12/12 11:34:04 [crit] 1051#100213: *5 connect() to unix:/home/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: <IP address>, server: <IP address>, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.sock:", host: "<IP address>"
```

My nginx processes:

```
root       1050   0.0  1.5  25496  7280  -  Is   11:11    0:00.00 nginx: master process /usr/local/sbin/nginx
www        1051   0.0  1.6  25496  7756  -  I    11:11    0:00.01 nginx: worker process (nginx)
```

I believe this is due to my uwsgi processes (emperor, master and workers) run as root while while nginx runs as `www`.

I've tried setting uwsgi's `gid` and `uid` to `www` but the uwsgi worker will fail with the following error:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Tue Dec 12 11:43:44 2017] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final 297347) on 08 December 2017 10:41:56
os: FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE-p4 FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p4 #0: Tue Nov 14 06:12:40 UTC 2017     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC
nodename: newyork
machine: amd64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /usr/home/ruipacheco
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi-2.7
chdir() to /home/dashboard/dashboard
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 2591]
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 1613]
Tue Dec 12 11:43:44 2017 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance /home/ruipacheco/uwsgi.ini (pid: 967)
Tue Dec 12 11:43:44 2017 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance /home/ruipacheco/uwsgi.ini
```

On the other hand if I leave it running as root nginx won't be able to connect to a socket owned by root.

What is the correct procedure to have nginx talk to a uwsgi socket on FreeBSD?

Comment: You need to check the ownership and permissions on the complete path to your socket.

Comment: What are the owner and permissions of each directory in the `/home/dashboard/dashboard` chain?

Comment: @RichardSmith The folders are owned by www:www